# Decompress equivalent in postgresql for compressed column

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I have SQL Server data where compressed data is stored like this:

[image]

After migrating to Postgresql, data is as above. How to get decompressed data in Postgresql?

Tried with decode function for Postgresql but with no luck.

```
SELECT CONVERT_FROM(decode(sdata,'escape'),'UTF8')::JSONB  
FROM dbo.s_table
```

> Error invalid input syntax for json

Comment: What exactly did you migrate to Postgres? If you migrated the binary data how was that constructed in the first place? You are looking for a postgres gzip decompress method. But if the binary data was constructed in SQL Server it may be using UCS-2 not UTF8 (If you called `COMPRESS` on an `nvarchar` value)

Comment: Migrate the decompressed data. According to [PostgreSQL gzip/gunzip Functions](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-gzip#postgresql-gzipgunzip-functions), PostgreSQL compresses large data anyway. [DECOMPRESS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/decompress-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) uses the Gzip algorithm.

Comment: @Martin Smith, Entire table is migrated to postgrsql. Now, I am unable to decompress that same column in postgreSql using methods available.

Comment: Based on the image ([Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)) it does look like the data is UTF-8 in SQL Server, @MartinSmith, as otherwise the OP wouldn't have got that non-Latin character.

Comment: @ThomA - Presumably they are storing the binary data resulting from compression in a completely inappropriate type (`nvarchar`) instead of storing it a `varbinary` - because there is no call to `COMPRESS` in that code

Comment: You can compare the byte values between the old and new table and see if they're the same, if not, Is the column in the target table of varchar type? Then i'm guessing you're smoked because it's probably mangled beyond recognition and you have an expensive book support of a server

Comment: You've got potentially multiple issues. The first is because you weren't storing binary data as binary data in the first place probably you've lost the original binary data anyway as Postgres probably uses a different text encoding for strings. And then even if you manage to get that back by converting to `UCS-2` so you can get the correct binary input to decompress it is unclear whether the result of decompression will also be in an encoding other than `UTF-8`

Comment: @synccm2012 SQL Server has transparent table compression. There never was any reason to use `COMPRESS` in the first place. The screenshot shows that the T-SQL query failed to decompress whatever is in `sdata`, so whatever is in PostgreSQL is already garbabe. Compressed data is binary and doesn't have to be cast to `varbinary(max)`. What is `sdata` and what does it *actually* contain? If the compressed data was encoded as text, eg BASE64, you'll have to reverse that encoding.

Comment: @synccm2012 can anyone read valid data from `sdata`? What query do they use to decode and decompress the data?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is there a simple way to `select` a value without decompressing? For storage, it sure is pointless to `compress()` hoping to save space - both DBs take care of that already. But for exposing data in its compressed form (for transfer, for whatever), it *could* be useful. What comes to mind is whether the behind-the-scenes compression is salvageable, or if `compress()` is necessary to "instruct" the db that you do want it compressed, but more importantly you don't want to get it back decompressed, unless explicitly requested with `decompress()`.

Comment: @Zegarek why? It matters. You're talking about compression over the wire, not storage compression. And that isn't worth the CPU and latency cost *unless* you're trying to connect to a remote database over a WAN, eg a cloud database. Data compression in SQL Server is completely transparent to the user, both for table data and backups. It's not affected nor does it use `COMPRESS`. It works on the entire row or data page, not individual columns. Check [Data Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Say you `insert` some big ol' text - both DB's compress it transparently. Now, your app wants it back, but still compressed. For that to happen, you need to run that text through `compress()` as a part of your `select` or that `insert` earlier. Question is: Is that necessary, or is there a simple way to let transparent compression occur but then prevent decompression when reading it back

Comment: @Zegarek my app doesn't want it compressed because it can't use it. `you need to run that text through compress()` no you don't, that would recompress the already compressed data. The client would have to decompress *twice*. This is a new question, not a comment. Post a new question explaining your *actual* problem. Until now you're asking about your assumed solution.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My question referred to your remark *There never was any reason to use COMPRESS in the first place.* Apologies if it came off confusing, annoying, offensive, or any combination of the three - you're most welcome to disregard the whole thing. Happy Festivus.

Comment: You should post a new question anyway. There may be answers for this already. You can enable compression at the VPN level for example, which would be cheaper than doing it on the server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos SQL Server does not compress LOB off-row data types, so `varchar(max)` and `nvarchar(max)` would not be compressed automatically, you do need `COMPRESS()`

Comment: Those scenarios (both external and large enough to require compression) are meant to use remote storage or specialized storage hardware. COMPRESS itself is slower than NTFS compression and even *that* is discouraged because of its impact. Deduplication, like that offered by ReFS or most storage solutions, is usually better. That's why I insist on the `why` so much. Compression steals RAM and CPU from the database server, which could be used to serve queries. Offloading that cost to the network or storage is probably better

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos .  sdata is a nvarchar column in sql server. A insert query compresses the data recieved from code and keeps it in sdata column. select query is used to  decompress  and being used. existing infra can'nt be changed need to know workaround after migrating to postgresql.

Comment: If the data wasn't mangled by the conversion to text, the `pgsql-gzip` extension may be able to decompress the data. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542543/is-it-possible-to-combine-net-gzip-compression-and-sql-server-compression) data compressed using `COMPRESS` are decompressed on the client using .NET's GZipStream

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos >8kb of off-row data is not large, I'd only recommend storing that in files if it was at least 1mb. If you have a lot of rows and the data is not frequently accessed then compression may be a good idea, and SQL Server does not compress it transparently as I said. Compression/decompression on the client might be another good option.